# Incorrect status bar style during launch on iPads running iOS/iPadOS 14

Tags: ios, uikit

In Xcode (12.0.1), you can set the initial style for the status bar in the general settings using the 'Status Bar Style' setting. If you choose *Dark Content*, you should get a dark status bar during launch, and if you choose *Light Content*, you should get a light status bar during launch.

This works as expected with most device and simulator configurations. However, on iPads running iOS/iPadOS 14 (both devices and simulators), most of the time at least, the 'Status Bar Style' setting seems to be ignored during the launch screen. Instead, the setting seems to be treated as *Default*, meaning the system chooses the status bar style for you based on the UI theme.

Is this a UIKit bug? Or could it be user error or a problem with my particular environment? Can anyone confirm the behavior described above?